# Call function based on a string

Tags: string, lisp, common-lisp

I am passing in command line arguments to my Lisp program and they are formatted like this when they hit my main function:

```
("1 1 1" "dot" "2 2 2")
```

I have a dot function (which takes two vectors as arguments) and would like to call it directly from the argument, but this isn't possible because something like (funcall (second args)...) receives `"dot"` and not `dot` as the function name.

I tried variations of this function:

```
(defun remove-quotes (s)
  (setf (aref s 0) '""))
```

to no avail, before realizing that the quotes were not really a part of the string.  Is there a simple way to do this, or should I just check each string and then call the appropriate function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`"1 1 1"` is a string of five characters: 1, space, 1, space and 1. The double quotes are not part of the string.

`("1 1 1" "dot" "2 2 2")` is a list of three strings.

There are no `"` characters above. The `"` are used to delimit strings in s-expressions.

If you have a dot function you need to tell us what kind of input data it expects.

Does it expect two lists of numbers? Then you have to convert the string `"1 1 1"` into a list of numbers.

```
(let ((cl:*read-eval* nil))
  (with-input-from-string (in "1 1 1")
    (loop for data = (read in nil in)
          until (eq data in)
          collect data))))
```

To get the function `DOT` from the string `"dot"` first find the symbol `DOT` and then get its symbol function.

```
(symbol-function (find-symbol (string-upcase "dot")))
```

For `find-symbol` one might need to specify also the package, if there is a special package where the symbol is in.

Converting a list to a vector then is the next building block.

So you need to convert the arguments for your function to vectors (probably first converting them to lists as I showed above). Then you need to find the function (see above). If you have then the function and the arguments, then you can call the function using `FUNCALL` or `APPLY` (whatever is more convenient).

Comment: I don't quite understand the iteration method above and I get an infinite loop when I attempt to run it.

Comment: @powerj1984 : I have replaced UNLESS with UNTIL. Should work now.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit unclear, but as far as I understand it you want, when given the list `("1 1 1" "dot" "2 2 2")` as input to evaluate the expression `(dot "1 1 1" "2 2 2")`. In that case you can do this:

```
(defun apply-infix (arg1 f arg2)
  (apply (intern (string-upcase f)) (list arg1 arg2)))
(defun apply-list-infix (lst)
  (apply 'apply-infix lst))

(apply-list-infix '("1 1 1" "dot" "2 2 2"))
```

Comment: Sorry my question is unclear, that is very similar to what I want - dot takes two vectors as arguments but you've got me on the right track, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`funcall` does not accept a string as a function designator.  You need to give it a symbol instead.  What you probably want to do is:

1. Convert the string to upper case (Lisp symbols are usually upper case, and even though it may look like Lisp is case-insensitive, that's just because the reader upcases all symbols it reads by default) (`string-upcase`).
2. Create or find a symbol with the given name (`intern`). Note that, if `*package*` is not set according to the package your function's name lives in, you need to supply the package name as the second argument to `intern`.

For instance (for a function named `dot` in package `cl-user`:

```
(funcall (intern (string-upcase "dot") 'cl-user) ...)
```